# Using Jquery UI sortable with css display: grid

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a sortable css grid using jquery UI.

```js
    $( function() {
     $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
       handle: "handle"
     });
    });
```

```css
    gridHolder{
      display:grid;
      background:tan;
      grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
    }
    gridHeader > *{
        padding:10px;
        background:yellow;
        border:thin solid black;
    }
    gridContent , gridHeader{
      display:contents;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<gridHolder id="sortable">
  <gridHeader>
 <handle>Handle</handle>
 <name>Name</name>
 <address>Address</address>
 <phone>Phone</phone>
  </gridHeader>
  <gridContent>
 <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Adam</name>
    <address>111 Main St</address>
    <phone>123-4567</phone> 
  </gridContent>  
  <gridContent>
 <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <address>222 Brown Ave</address>
    <phone>987-6543</phone> 
  </gridContent>  
  <gridContent>
 <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Carl</name>
    <address>333 East Ave</address>
    <phone>555-1343</phone> 
  </gridContent>    
  
</gridHolder>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lj9wnh7x/6/

The issue I am running into is the sortable doesn't seem to work properly with the css grid and display:contents property. 
I understand that display:contents is not so much a display as much as a organizer for children elements but I can't see how it would effect the jquery ui sortable.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: I am trying to get the grid rows sortable. They should be draggable via the 'handle' item. 
Currently the element panel (in chrome) shows them being moved, but they do not display as such.

Comment: @Robbie since you are not using conventional `<ul><li>` you will want to define the `items` for sortable. Also do you want the header to get sorted as well as content?

Comment: Also I am not familiar with this markup. Can you link to the CSS You're using or a tutorial?

Comment: This is just styled XML for ease of reading. Another user posted it using traditional HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, on a fundamental CSS Level, the `grid` content cannot be sorted, dragged, or moved.

> **Note:** `float`, `display: inline-block`, `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align` and `column-*` properties have no effect on a grid item.

I suspect that the lack of these properties causes jQuery UI to be unable to manage DnD properly.

This is what I tested with, following proper HTML/CSS Syntax, and it still does not work:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: ".handle",
    items: "> div.gridContent"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.gridHolder {
  display: grid;
  background: tan;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
}

.gridHeader>* {
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.gridContent,
.gridHeader {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="gridHolder" id="sortable">
  <div class="gridHeader">
    <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Name</name>
    <address>Address</address>
    <phone>Phone</phone>
  </div>
  <div class="gridContent">
    <div class="handle">Handle</div>
    <div class="name">Adam</div>
    <div class="address">111 Main St</div>
    <div class="phone">123-4567</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridContent">
    <div class="handle">Handle</div>
    <div class="name">Jenny</div>
    <div class="address">222 Brown St</div>
    <div class="phone">867-5309</div>
  </div>
  <div class="gridContent">
    <div class="handle">Handle</div>
    <div class="name">Carl</div>
    <div class="address">222 Brown St</div>
    <div class="phone">555-1212</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Still doing some research to see if this is the case.

**Update**

> Another issue to be aware of in CSS Grid Layout and to a lesser extent in CSS Flexbox, is the temptation to flatten markup. As we have discovered, for an item to become a grid item it needs to be a direct child of the grid container. Therefore, where you have a `<ul>` element inside a grid container, that ul becomes a grid item – the child `<li>` elements do not.

[See More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_Layout_and_Accessibility#Grid_and_the_danger_of_markup_flattening).

So it's the structure relationship, child and parent, that is causing an issue here. Here is another example that is working.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: "handle"
  });
  $("#sortable").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
#sortable {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gridHolder {
  background: tan;
}

.gridHolder li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 2fr;
}

.gridHeader * {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  border: thin solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="gridHolder" id="sortable">
  <li class="gridHeader row">
    <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Name</name>
    <address>Address</address>
    <phone>Phone</phone>
  </li>
  <li class="gridContent">
    <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Adam</name>
    <address>111 Main St</address>
    <phone>123-4567</phone>
  </li>
  <li class="gridContent">
    <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Bob</name>
    <address>222 Brown Ave</address>
    <phone>987-6543</phone>
  </li>
  <li class="gridContent">
    <handle>Handle</handle>
    <name>Carl</name>
    <address>333 East Ave</address>
    <phone>555-1343</phone>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The only issue with that though is when you remove the 'display: content;' it does work as expected... kinda.

Comment: Still researching and that is something to check.

Comment: @Robbie update my answer. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_Layout_and_Accessibility#Grid_and_the_danger_of_markup_flattening

Comment: Awesome. It seems like this is going to be an issue until the 'subgrid' display mode comes around, but at least in the meantime there is a 'hack' to make it work. :)